# If $e^{Ty}$ is a Floquet multiplier, then there is a solution of the form $x(t)=e^{yt}p(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

question:

Let $A(t)$ be a continuous, non-constant, real matrix-valued, $T>0$ periodic function $A(t+T)=A(t)$. For the system $$\dot x =A(t)x$$ we want to show that if $e^{Ty}$ is a Floquet multiplier, then there is a solution of the form $x(t)=e^{yt}p(t)$.

Here it is picture wise...
[image]

I am a bit stuck on this. Here is what I have done so far:

I know that the solution to our ode looks like $$x(t)=X(t)x_0$$

I know that given $X(t)$ is a fundamental matrix (fm), we know $X(t+T)$ is a fm as well. Then, we know that there exists a matrix M (monodromy matrix) such that $$X(t+T)=X(t)M$$

Then by the existence of matrix log, we have that there is a matrix B so that $$M=e^{BT}$$

Then, let $p(t)=X(t)e^{-Bt}$.

$X(T+t)=X(t+T)e^{-B(t+T)}=X(t+T)e^{-Bt}e^{-BT}=X(t)Me^{B(t+T)}=X(t)e^{-Bt}=p(t)$. So we have $$X(t)=p(t)e^{Bt}$$

Plugging that into the solution we get $$x(t)=p(t)e^{Bt}x_0$$ and so for $x_0=1$ we get $$x(t)=p(t)e^{Bt}$$
But I am confused how to use the fact that $e^{Ty}$ are floqeut multipliers and how to get them involved in the solution.

I know that the floquet multipliers are the eigenvalues of $X(T)$.

Comment: What is $y$ in the $e^{Ty}$?

Comment: @Chee Han I’m not entirely sure. I will add the problem to the question above. I’m trying to do part b.

Comment: You should try to type out the question next time instead of posting a photo. Anyway, $\gamma$ is known as the Floquet exponent.

Comment: Thank you. I did type the question at the top of my question though. But I will edit it to make it more clear. :) very much appreciate your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me state a theorem first.

> Theorem 1: Suppose $A(\cdot)$ is a $T$-periodic continuous matrix-valued function. The non-autonomous linear system $\dot{x} = A(t)x$ has at least one non-trivial solution $X(t)$ satisfying $X(t+T) = \mu X(t), t\in(-\infty,\infty)$, where $\mu$ is a Floquet multiplier.

Let us denote the system $\dot{x} = A(t)x$ by (#). Given $e^{T\gamma}$ is a Floquet multiplier (now if I understand you correctly, then $\gamma\in\mathbb{C}$ should be the corresponding Floquet exponent), Theorem 1 asserts that there exists a non-trivial solution $X(t)$ of (#) such that 
$$ X(t + T) = e^{T\gamma}X(t). $$
In particular, 
\begin{align*}
X(t) & = X(t+T)e^{-T\gamma} \\
& = \Big[e^{\gamma t}e^{-\gamma t}\Big]X(t+T)e^{-T\gamma } \\
& = e^{\gamma t}\Big(X(t+T)e^{-\gamma (t+T)}\Big) \\
& = e^{\gamma t}p(t+T) \\
& = e^{\gamma t}p(t)
\end{align*}
where $p(t) = X(t)e^{-\gamma t}$ is $T$-periodic.

Comment: I assume you are aware of the result from Theorem 1. If not, you may look at my ODE notes (http://www.math.utah.edu/~tan/notes.html), in particular Section 2.3.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the help a ton.